# horizontally view next/prev videos

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a set of videos displayed inline. I want to display one video at a time and display the rest on click.

**HTML**

```
<div class="top-videos">
<h3>Top Videos</h3>
<a href="#"><img src="images/example.jpg" width=225/></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/example.jpg" width=225/></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/example.jpg" width=225/></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/example.jpg" width=225/></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/example.jpg" width=225/></a>

<nav class="previous">Previous</nav>
<nav class="next">Next</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are the videos? I guess you have to learn a bit of Javascript / jQuery.

Comment: i dont have any knowledge in javascript or jquery. Just a regular guy looking for some code to put in my website. Could you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have this example:

http://ikillcraft.a0001.net/slider/jcontent-video-example.htm

Download:

http://www.purosoftware.com/desarrollo-web-scripts-manipulacion-de-imagenes/descargar/10-jcontent-ejemplos-para-crear-sliders-de-contenido-html-fotos-videos-con-jquery-y-ajax.zip

Manual (it's in Spanish)

http://www.purosoftware.com/desarrollo-web-scripts-manipulacion-de-imagenes/10-slider-de-contenido-e-imagenes.html

I have try a JSFiddle but it doesn't work. :(